# Pointer in C++ copy constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, copy

I try to learn copy constructors principle.

I have this code and I need to COPY data to testB data type.

Right now, I only copy pointers to previous memory but I need to copy all data.

Can you help me?

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Test {
    int i, *p;

    Test(int i): i(i), p(new int[i]){
        
        p[0] = 1;
        p[1] = 2;
        p[2] = 3;

    }
    ~Test() {

    }
};
struct TestB : Test {
    
    TestB(const Test &test) : Test(test){
        p = new int[3];
        p[0] = test.p[0];
        p[1] = test.p[1];
        p[2] = test.p[2];
        i = test.i;
    }
};

int main(){
    Test test(3);
    TestB b = test;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The constructor of `TestB` depends on the copy constructor of `Test`. It is better if you dedicate some though to implement the copy constructor of `Test` first.

Comment: There are no copy constructors defined in this code.

Comment: You are better off using `std::vector<int>` instead of the self-managed dynamic array.

Comment: The rule of 3 specifies you need a copy assignment operator too.

Comment: TestB(const Test &test) : Test(test) is inheriting default copy constructor? Why? I think that's not the copy constructor you want to invoke. I think you should define a base copy constructor.

Comment: @DrewDormann yes there is copy constructor in TestB.

Answer (score 0):

First off, what you are trying to implement is a [*converting* constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor), not a [*copy* constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), since you are trying to *convert* a `Test` object into a `TestB` object, rather than create a copy of a `TestB` object from another `TestB` object.

Since the array exists in `Test`, you should implement an actual *copy* constructor (and a *copy assignment* operator) in `Test`, and then `TestB`'s *converting* constructor can call `Test`'s *copy* constructor.  `Test`'s *copy* constructor can then allocate a new array that has the same number of items as the array being copied, and copy the values from the original array into the new array, eg:

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct Test {
    int i, *p;

    Test(int i): i(i), p(new int[i]) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            p[j] = j+1;
    }

    Test(const Test &src): i(src.i), p(new int[src.i]) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            p[j] = src.p[j];
    }

    ~Test() {
        delete[] p;
    }

    // don't forget an assignment operator too, per the Rule of 3:
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three
    Test& operator=(const Test &rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            Test tmp(rhs);
            std::swap(i, tmp.i);
            std::swap(p, tmp.p);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

struct TestB : Test {
    TestB(const Test &test) : Test(test) {}
};

int main(){
    Test test(3);
    TestB b = test;
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, you should use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`, then you get all of the array management for free since `std::vector` already implements everything for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct Test {
    std::vector<int> p;

    Test(int i): p(i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            p[j] = j+1;
    }
};

struct TestB : Test {
    TestB(const Test &test) : Test(test) {}
};

int main(){
    Test test(3);
    TestB b = test;
    return 0;
}
```